# Graphql requests returning 429, but working fine when using http.client or when running curl in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, graphql, httpclient, http-status-code-429

Using below requests returns 429 status code, but when same request is used in curl, and by using Python http.client library, i get 200 status code and data.

What can be issue where requests gives 429 but I get data through other clients and in curl

````
            url="www.xyz.co.in/graphql",
            headers={
                "User-Agent": "CFNetwork/1485 Darwin/23.1.0",
                "Client-Info": "ios.com.expedia.booking,2023.45,external",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            data=json.dumps({
                "query": query,
                "variables": variables
            })
        ) ```
````

Comment: Could you update your question to provide a bit more information on the request? What you've provided now doesn't show `query` or `variables`.  
Without that, it looks to me like your issue is a matter of rate-limiting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429.